# Can you learn something "by proxy"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Say you're transcribing a foreign language and it takes you many times before you can accurately transcribe what is being said but as a by-product at least "by proxy" you're improving your listening skill.

Comment: Repetition is the key to acquiring/learning/ **assimilating** a new language, the fact you listened repetitively to natural speech meant your brain became accustomed to its sounds and began to recognize speech patterns.  I don't think that can be called *proxy*.

Comment: You can get married by proxy, and you can learn by example or reading or translating or repetition, but you cannot learn by proxy. Learning requires your activity, your input.

Comment: The prepositions _by_ (agency, method, during), _from_ (origin) and _through_ (using, as a result of) alone suffice [between](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=learn+%2A+example&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Clearn%20%2A%20example%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blearn%20by%20example%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blearn%20from%20example%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blearn%20for%20example%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blearn%20through%20example%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blearn%20the%20example%3B%2Cc0) the words _learn_ and _example_; I find that telling, whether what happens is intended or not.

Answer (score 2):

[Proxy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/proxy) is a formal expression with the following meanings:

> - the agency, function, or power of a person authorized to act as the deputy or substitute for another.
> - the person so authorized; substitute; agent.
> - a written authorization empowering another person to vote or act for the signer, as at a meeting of stockholders.
>     (Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary)
>
>   - *to vote by proxy*; *whether in person or by proxy*.

The Free Dictionary

- Regarding your sentence, you may say that *as a  consequence* or *as a result* you are improving your listening skills.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, "by proxy" would mean here **borrowing someone else's brain** for the learning process :-)

Thus it doesn't work.